# Не работает модальное окно

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Само модальное окно выводится на экран, но то, что находится в `modal-body` - нет.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#dopinf" class="btn">Доп. инф.</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="dopinf">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Дополнительная информация</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <table>
               <thead>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        Дом
                     </td>
                     <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        Квартира
                     </td>
                     <td></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-small" data-dismiss="modal">Выход</button>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что беда в CSS
.modal-body{display: none;}?

Comment: Покажите `CSS` код

Comment: Этот блок кода рабочий [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ougr988h/). Ищите проблему в обработчиках событий, стилях и всем остальном, что влияет на этот кусок кода.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас с CSS стоит на .modal-body какое-то ограничивающее видимость свойство. Вызовите модальное окно и ткните в него правой кнопкой. В инспекторе посмотрите какие css стоят на нём. Если там что-то вроде visibility: hidden или  z-index маленький, попробуйте поменять эти параметры. Если это поможет, то смотрите где установлено и почему не меняется это свойство. Можно попробовать внести эти правки из инспектора на сайт. Если и так не работает, то создайте новую страницу (пустую) и последовательно добавляйте в неё кусок за куском, проверяя их работоспособность, соответственно начать надо с модального окна.

Comment: Вообще учитесь пользоваться инспектором http://joxi.ru/a2XDKXyTjxWk2g он обычно рассказывает о подавляющем большинстве проблем. Есть хороший курс но на английском: http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com

Answer (score 0):

просто вставляем код в боди(modal-body) и все работает

```
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

[рабочая версия тут](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_js&stacked=h)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <table>
               <thead>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        Дом
                     </td>
                     <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        Квартира
                     </td>
                     <td></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У него код точно такого же типа, но не работает..

Comment: все еще не отображается содержимое body, было сделано по этому же примеру

Comment: скопируйте коде которыj я выставил, должно работать